# Calculate the sum of the counts of a factor variable, as a subset of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sum, factors

I am trying to get a summary of how many people in my data have had surgery and then gone on to die; to calculate the mortality rate for surgery patients.

My data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
y1988 = rep(c('Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'M', 'D', 'Y', 'Y', 'D', 'X', 'D'), 25),
y1989 = rep(c('Y', 'M', 'D', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'), 25),
y1990 = rep(c('D', 'Y', 'D', 'X', 'Y', 'M', 'D', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'), 25),
y1991 = rep(c('D', 'Y', 'Y', 'M', 'D', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'D', 'Y'), 25),
age = rep(20:69, 5),
ID = (1:250)
)
```

What I want to do is get a sum of the number of 'D' and divide this by the number of 'Y' for age per year (y1988 to y1991).

If I were to do this manually, I would subset the dataframe for each age, and then divide the sum of 'D' by the sum of 'Y', eg

```
a21 <- filter(df, age == 21)
a21$mort1988 <- sum(a21$y1988 == 'D') / sum(a21$y1988 == 'Y')
a21$mort1989 <- sum(a21$y1989 == 'D') / sum(a21$y1989 == 'Y')
```

etc

This seems absurd, is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Most of the calculations based on the data you provided are getting `NaN` (may be because there are not many values in the data to check it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at` to do the division for each of the `yYear` columns after grouping by 'age'

```
df %>% 
    group_by(age) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(matches("y\\d{4}")), funs(sum(.=="D")/sum(.=="Y")))
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run this code, I get a new value for each row in my data. So I get an estimate of mortality for each ID number. What I'd like as output is a new dataframe, with only one row for each age, so 50 rows in total. Is this possible?

Comment: @Laura Sorry, it should be `summarise_at` instead of `mutate_at`.  corrected

Comment: Thank you heaps Akrun, much appreciated